# React Fetch Google Cloud Function http cors req.method OPTIONS, POST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

> save time and skip to answer

What's wrong with my axios 'GET' `this.props.profile.id` logs into the console correctly from `react-redux-firebase`, but that's another story.

```
...

const response = await axios.get(
  "https://us-central1-thumbprint-1c31n.cloudfunctions.net/listCharts",
  { 'seatsioid': this.props.profile.id }
);
```

Or cloud functions header?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
//const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { SeatsioClient } = require('seatsio')
const cors = require('cors')
//admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.listCharts = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, async () => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://1c31n.csb.app');
    //res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type', 'X-Requested-Width', 'Accept', 'seatsioid')
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '60');
  var allowedOrigins = ['https://1c31n.csb.app', 'https://1c31n.codesandbox.io'];
  var origin = req.headers.origin;
  if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1){}
  const seatsioid = **req.get('seatsioid')
  let clientAdmin = new SeatsioClient('<THIS_IS_MY_ADMIN_SEATSIO_secretKey>')
  let subaccountInfo = await clientAdmin.subaccounts.retrieve(seatsioid);
  let secretKey = subaccountInfo.secretKey
  let clientDesignerKey = subaccountInfo.designerKey
  let charts = []
  let clientUser = new SeatsioClient(secretKey)
  for await(let chart of clientUser.charts.listAll()){
    charts.push(`chart":"${chart.key}`)
    }
    let couple = {
      charts,
      clientDesignerKey
    }
    res.send(couple)
})
})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This took dayssss for me. hopefully this helps readers

> express' cors middleware :
> https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html
>
> Google Cloud Function abstraction for cors middleware : https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http
>
> Call GCFunctions thru http (for fetch) :
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

React fetch(URL, {})

```
async componentDidMount() {
    //console.log(this.props.profile)
    //this.setState({ posterOptions: this.props.profile.pages.unshift('post as myself')})
    //const seatsioid = this.props.profile.id;
    await fetch(
      "https://us-central1-foldername.cloudfunctions.net/function",
      {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "Application/JSON",
          "Access-Control-Request-Method": "POST"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ seatsioid: this.props.profile.id }),
        maxAge: 3600
        //"mode": "cors",
      }
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(body => {
        console.log(body);
        //const reader = response.body.getReader()
        //reader.read().then(value => {
        //console.log(value);
        this.setState({
          allCharts: body.couple[0].charts,
          secretKey: body.couple[0].secretKey
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Google Cloud Function

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { SeatsioClient } = require("seatsio");
const cors = require("cors")({
  origin: true,
  allowedHeaders: [
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "Content-Type",
    "Origin",
    "X-Requested-With",
    "Accept"
  ],
  methods: ["POST", "OPTIONS"],
  credentials: true
});

exports.listCharts = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // Google Cloud Function res.methods
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  res.set("Content-Type", "Application/JSON");
  // CORS-enabled req.methods, res.methods
  return cors(req, res, async () => {
    res.set("Content-Type", "Application/JSON");
    var origin = req.get("Origin");
    var allowedOrigins = [
      "https://www.yoursite.blah",
      "https://yoursite2.blah"
    ];
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
      // Origin Allowed!!
      res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
      if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        // Method accepted for next request
        res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
        //SEND or end
        return res.status(200).send({});
      } else {
          // After req.method === 'OPTIONS' set ["Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST"]
          // req.method === 'POST' with req.body.{name} => res.body.{name}
          // req.method === 'PUT' with req.body.{name}, no res.body.{name}
        let couple = [];
        if (req.body.seatsioid) {
          const seatsioid = req.body.seatsioid;
          let clientAdmin = new SeatsioClient("YOUR_ADMIN_KEY");
          let subaccountInfo = await clientAdmin.subaccounts.retrieve(seatsioid);
          let secretKey = subaccountInfo.secretKey;
          let charts = [];
          let clientUser = new SeatsioClient(secretKey);
          for await (let chart of clientUser.charts.listAll()) {
            charts.push(`chart":"${chart.key}`);
          }
          couple = [
            {
              charts: charts,
              secretKey: secretKey
            }
          ];
          //SEND or end
          res.status(200).send({ couple });
        } else {
          //SEND or end
          res.status(400).send("No seatsioid defined!");
        }
      }
    } else {
      //Origin Bad!!
      //SEND or end
      return res.status(400).send("no access for this origin");
    }
  });
});
```

Someone with 1500 rep points should maybe add the seatsio tag in replace of reactjs or javascript for their other users, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Normally, in the Cloud Functions `index.js` file, you should declare `cors` as follows:

```
const cors = require('cors')({
    origin: true
});
```

This is the way to allow current request origin, or, in other words "to reflect the request origin", see https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Also see the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Comment: Isn't that a wildcard?  Docs say wildcard cors origins are not "accepted" 
 https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http.  They're right, I'm still blocked. ````Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-central1-thumbprint-1c31n.cloudfunctions.net/listCharts' from origin 'https://1c31n.csb.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.````

Comment: This is the way to allow current request origin, or, in other words "to reflect the request origin", see https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: Thanks but "to allow current request origin" is a "wildward" which cloud functions do not accept

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "which cloud functions does not accept", but this is the way that is indicated in the Fiebase doc (see link at the end of the answer), in some **official** Cloud Functions samples (https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/3bbad47cdab8606bf3a52e0119f7b2cc5ca53992/quickstarts/time-server/functions/index.js or https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/6c284a689c484ac4395fde1a8e8d6c2731705b55/username-password-auth/functions/index.js) and the way it works in some of my own Cloud Functions.

Comment: Ok actually my mistake Google Cloud Functions docs say under "Authentication Cors" via firebase wildcard (I'm assuming ({origin: true}) is too) isn't "allowed"... Although instead of using firebase auth I am just passing a variable from react-redux variable 'seatsioid' in a header of the axios get.  Those examples don't take any headers. As far I can tell..

Comment: It should be the same whether you pass some extra headers or not (if I am not mistaking).

Comment: you were right! check out my answer. set the origin from req.get("Origin") using "Origin" header, after origin: true in cors middeware  thanks Renaud